# Unable to insert data into MySQL DB using flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that connects to a MySQL DB and retrieves the data but it cannot insert anything into it. I am using flask-SQLAlchemy and the form is generated using flaskwtforms. Below is the model

```
class Name(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'names'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)

def __init__(self, id, name, password):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.password = password

def __rep__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Below is the form itself

```
class AddUser(FlaskForm):
name = StringField(label= 'username', validators = [InputRequired('Username is required')])
password = StringField(label = 'password', validators = [InputRequired('Password is required')])
```

Below is the view function

```
@app.route('/add_user', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_user():
form = AddUser()

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit(): 
    name = form.name.data
    password = form.password.data
    name = Name(name,password)
    db.session.add(name)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('add-user.html')

else:
    return render_template('add-user.html', form=form)
```

Comment: What is your error message? Do you have write permissions?

Comment: There is no error message, and I am using the root user to do all DB activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. So in my database, the id is set as the primary key and is auto-generated hence it does not need to be passed in the constructor since my query would also require me to pass an id.